# Как уменьшить время поиска в массиве строк (большое число)?

Tags: linux, c, алгоритм

У меня имеются списки на разный страницах:

```
1. Title 1
2. Title 2
   2.1. Title 2.1 (Новый список на новой странице).
   2.2  Title 2.2 
3. Title 3
```

При переключении стрелкой клавиатуры между элементами списка, рядом в окошке появляется текстовое описание элемента.

Каждому элементу списка присвоен тег (массив тегов, `char*`), по которому ищется описание элемента списка. Теги сравниваются функцией `strcmp()`.

Как уменьшить время поиска тега в массиве, если я буду использовать один массив, и в нем будет много элементов? Ведь еще время идет на сравнение.
Была идея использовать разные массивы тегов для разных списков, то есть каждому списку нужно будет присваивать некий id и использовать несколько массивов.
Что можно еще реализовать? Язык: Чистый C.

Comment: Вы уверены, что время поиска критично? Даже если у вас будет линейный поиск, расходы на него обычно намного меньше, чем, скажем, ожидание ввода с клавиатуры. Может, у вас strcmp в цикле?

Comment: @VladD в цикле for сравниваю текст активного элемента списка с каждым элементом массива. Если элемент будет в конце массива, придется ждать, пока не пройдет весь массив,

Comment: А какой размер массива? Хоть приблизительно? Десять элементов? Тысяча? Миллион?

Comment: 300 элементов. Строки.

Comment: 300 сравнений строк должно быть мгновенно, по идее. А какая длина строки? (Может, у вас строка, с который вы сравниваете, по ошибке не заканчивается на `\0`?)

Comment: Или у вас древний процессор, типа i286?

Comment: @VladD 20 элементов примерно. Обычные строки char*. "Hello world". Насколько я знаю, вручную символ окончания строки не нужно проставлять. Древний.

Comment: @VladD тут на хабре вычитал, можно по хешу, какие-то ассоциативные массивы... Можно ли это в си сделать вопрос. Константная сложность будет. Не зависит от количества элементов

Comment: Ну хеш-то можно, но в вашем случае 300 strcmp маленьких строк на одно ожидание ввода с клавиатуры не должно приводить к тормозам. Боюсь, ваша проблема где-то ещё.

Comment: @VladD у меня пока не тормозит. Я еще только пишу этот массив строк. И чтобы время попусту не потратил, интересуюсь, как можно оптимизировать. Но Вы сказали, что это быстро должно пройти. Сравнение строк в процессоре быстро происходит?

Comment: Ну, процессор строки не сравнивает, функция `strcmp` сравнивает их [можно считать что] посимвольно. Одно сравнение символов порядка наносекунды. 300 строк по 30 символов ≈ 10000 сравнений, занимает порядка 10 микросекунд. Ну там если я ошибся на порядок, будет одна миллисекунда. Так что пока не парьтесь. Решайте проблемы по мере их возникновения. Будет медленно — перепишете, делов-то!

Comment: Если уж так хотите реально оптимизировать, то измените структуру данных. Замените (или дополните) тэг, связанный с каждой строкой на указатель прямо на текст, который сейчас ищете по тэгу (если я правильно понял Ваше описание). Естественно, при загрузке (инициализации) всей этой структуры (я не имею в виду именно `struct { ... }`) потребуется однократный поиск по тэгу и далее установка указателя. / (и запомните,  *истинная эффективность определяется алгоритмами и подходящими структурами данных* (не обессудьте, цитировал кого-то из уже классиков по памяти))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если время критично - по завершению загрузки данных сортируйте массив тегов любым не самым медленным способом(сортировкой Шелла например), после чего ищите строку в массиве с помощью бинарного поиска.

Например:

```
long int searchBinary(dio_table *t, const requestData *rdata) //t - структура с массивом указателей на строки и их количеством, rdata - данные для поиска
{
    lint bottom = 0; // Индекс начала поиска
    lint mid = 0; 
    lint top = t->head.count - 1; //Индекс конца поиска

    while(bottom <= top){
        mid = (bottom + top)/2; 
        int cmpr = strcmp (t->lines[mid].data, rdata->col); 
        //t->lines[mid].data получаем строку по середине, сравниваем с rdata->col
        if (cmpr == 0){ // Если нашли искомую строку, то ее и возвращаем
            return mid;
        } else if (cmpr > 0){ // Если сравнение вернуло положительное число, значит искомая строка где-то выше по списку
            top = mid - 1;
        } else if (cmpr < 0){ // Или ниже
            bottom = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1; // Если ничего не нашли
}
```

Вот примерно так.

Но повторюсь:

```
Такой поиск работает ТОЛЬКО в отсортированном массиве!
```

UPD: сортировка массива должна вестись по возрастанию

Comment: поспорил бы, что это оптимально для поиска строки, тут сложность O( ln (count) * lenght) а с помощью бор или хеш-таблицы можно за O(length). Правда и памяти больше будет использовано.

Comment: @pavel со сложностью вы немного переборщили, но в плане скорости хеш-таблица может быть действительно быстрее. А может и нет :)